# Definition of fences in plotly's boxplot

Tags: python, plotly, boxplot, plotly-express

How are lower and upper fences computed in plotly's boxplot function, i.e. plotly.express.box() resp. plotly.graph_objects.Box?

I can’t find anything about that in the documentation which is strange, as there are multiple ways to define the fences/whiskers…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be in the docs and will be soon:

> Each box spans from quartile 1 (Q1) to quartile 3 (Q3). The second
>   quartile (Q2) is marked by a line inside the box. By default, the
>   whiskers correspond to the boxes' edges +/- 1.5 times the
>   interquartile range (IQR: Q3-Q1)

[Source: Plotly.js source code description](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/dba8f5543e8c400a7c3d90f2731641006748f919/src/traces/box/index.js#L39)

Comment: @nicolaskrutchen how could the box plots be asymmetric then? I.e., the lower fence sometimes is much further than the upper fence (or vice versa) from their respective box edges (Q1 or Q3).

Comment: I should update this answer: Plotly follows the usual convention of having the whisker extend to the point farthest from the corresponding fence which is still within 1.5*IQR of the fence.

Answer (score 0):

Putting @nicolaskruchten comments in an answer:
The labelled "upper fence" and "lower fence" in the plotly barplot (and violin plot) hover text point at the ends of the whiskers.
The whiskers extend to the point closest to, but within, 1.5 * IQR where
IQR is the interquartile range, 75th percentile - 25th percentile.