# How to remove ggplotly boxplot outliers but show jitter points

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

I haven't seen a consistent approach to not show outliers of boxplots in ggplotly. I'm using boxplots combined with geom_jitter, so I don't want the boxplot outlier to show, but it doesn't work the same way as it works with ggplot (which is basically `outlier.shape = NA`)

```
library(pacman)
pacman::p_load(dplyr, ggplot2, plotly)


g <- ggplot(chickwts %>% dplyr::filter(feed == "sunflower"),
            aes(x = factor(feed), y = weight, fill = factor(feed))) + 
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) + 
  geom_jitter(alpha = 0.5, height = 0)

plot(g)
```

[image: g]

```
ggplotly(g)
```

[image: ggplotly(g)]

Comment: This seems very similar to some prior questions, do these answers work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59384604/remove-outliers-from-a-ggplotly-boxplot or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72092591/remove-whiskers-and-outliers-in-r-plotly or https://stackoverflow.com/a/59823226/6851825

Comment: @JonSpring Unfortunately I don't think they solve the problem. They either make the outlier points invisible (but you'll see their values if you move your mouse on them) or they get rid of all points at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

**Revised answer**: Here's another try, for this specific case. It's hack-y but I think it removes the points in the way you're looking for. Use the [following description of how plotly calculates the whiskers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57588018/definition-of-fences-in-plotlys-boxplot) to subset the points to only those between the lower and upper whiskers of the boxplot.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
g <- ggplot(chickwts %>% dplyr::filter(feed == "sunflower"),
            aes(x = factor(feed), y = weight, fill = factor(feed))) + 
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) + 
  geom_jitter(alpha = 0.5, height = 0)

# Modify the plotly object to remove the points beyond the whiskers
g <- plotly_build(g)

# grab the y values 
vals <- g$x$data[[1]]$y
# calculate the interquartile range
iqr<-IQR(vals)
# find values for the upper and lower fence 
# following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57588018/definition-of-fences-in-plotlys-boxplot
min.max<-quantile(vals)[c(2,4)]+c(-1.5*iqr,1.5*iqr)
# keep only y values between the upper and lower fence
g$x$data[[1]]$y<-vals[vals>=min.max[1]&vals<=min.max[2]]

g
```

**Original answer**: It seems like this is a known issue. For example, see this issue on the `plotly` Github: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/issues/1114 Following the conversation and suggestions on that page, you might try the following for your example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
g <- ggplot(chickwts %>% dplyr::filter(feed == "sunflower"),
            aes(x = factor(feed), y = weight, fill = factor(feed))) + 
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) + 
  geom_jitter(alpha = 0.5, height = 0)

# Need to modify the plotly object and make outlier points have opacity equal to 0
g <- plotly_build(g)

g$x$data[1] <- lapply(g$x$data[1], FUN = function(x){
  x$marker = list(opacity = 0)
  return(x)
})

g
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Unfortunately the points are still there, but they're invisible. So if you move your mouse over them, you'll still see their value.